# Ansible playbook to update all packages except kernel not working

Tags: yum, ansible

I'm attempting to write an Ansible playbook to update all packages except the kernel.  Whenever I run the following playbook, all packages get updated, including the kernel.  Any ideas why my exclude parameter is being ignored?

```
  - name: upgrade all packages, excluding kernel
    yum:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
      exclude: kernel*
```

Comment: Apparently, that very use case is documented: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html. Your snippet "should" work, AFAIU. Might be worth asking on GitHub, open an issue.

Comment: You may also want to ask on the `#ansible` irc channel.

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me at ansible 2.9.  The only difference from your playbook is that I have quotes around kernel*:

```
  - name: upgrade all packages, excluding kernel
    yum:
      name: '*'
      state: latest
      exclude: 'kernel*'
```